# How to make middle div the first on smaller screen

Tags: css

I have 3 divs that are displayed side by side when the screen is wide:

```
<div class="div1"></div><div class="div2"></div><div class="div3"></div>
```

---

### |   div1      |   div2   |   div3   |

(all are just floating left)

These are working fine but when the screen gets smaller, I want them to display as:

---

### |           div2                |

### |  div1       |  div3           |

so what was the middle div has to be pulled out and made the top div

can I do this with css?

any ideas?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with only css. need js to switch content in div1 and div2 when window is resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to edit the HTML and use absolute positioning? I tend to work from smaller screen to larger screen and one option is to then use the following:

HTML

```
<div class="div2"></div><div class="div1"></div><div class="div3"></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    float: left;
}
```

Then, when the screen is large enough (using mediaqueries to check):
HTML stays the same

CSS

```
div.div1 {
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
div.div2 {
    display: inline; /* pesky older IE */
    margin-left: "width of div.div1 (%/em/px)";
}
```